# All possible replacements of an expression, considering each term separately

Tags: replacement

Say I have an expression:

```
f[a, f[a, b]]
```

I would like to replace each `a` with either `x` or `y`. By using `Replace`, I can do

```
Replace[f[a, f[a, b]], {{a -> x}, {a -> y}}, All]
```

Which gives

> ```
> {
>  f[x, f[x, b]],
>  f[y, f[y, b]]
> }
> ```

However, I'd like to get (in any order)

> ```
> {
>  f[x, f[x, b]],
>  f[x, f[y, b]],
>  f[y, f[x, b]],
>  f[y, f[y, b]]
> }
> ```

Essentially, each term is considered separately.

I've tried looking in the documentation for functions similar to `Replace`, but to no avail. How do I go about this? Thanks in advance!

---

*Edit*

I feel I should've been more precise in my original question. For some nested expression like `f[x, f[x, x]]`, I need a list of expressions where some (or all or none) of the `f`'s are replaced by `g`'s. Only `f`'s which take `x` as their first argument may be replaced; the rest are left unchanged.

For example, an input of

```
f[f[x, x], x]
```

Should give (in any order)

> ```
> {
>  f[f[x, x], x],
>  f[g[x, x], x]
> }
> ```

Notice how the first `f` has not been replaced, since it does not have `x` as its first argument.

I hope that this rephrasing is not distruptive. If I should instead ask this as a separate question, please tell me!

Comment: `Map[f[#[[1]],f[#[[2]],b]]&,Tuples[{x,y},2]]` instantly gives you the list of results `{f[x,f[x,b]], f[x,f[y,b]], f[y,f[x,b]], f[y,f[y,b]]}`

Comment: @Bill Thanks! How might I package this up into a function, e.g. `replacePerTerm`?

Answer (score 1):

One possible (and fairly direct) approach is to convert all instances of the symbol to replace into unique versions of that symbol, and then replace each in turn. Automating this is a bit tricky though. I broke this problem up into 3 separate helper functions based around using `tmp$n` variables as a name space:

```
tmpvalQ[x_Symbol] := StringMatchQ[SymbolName[x], "tmp$" ~~ __];
```

This is a helper function which determines if its input is a symbol starting with `tmp$`.

```
getreplacements[expr_, replf_] := 
  Map[replf, 
   DeleteDuplicates[
    Cases[expr, (x_?tmpvalQ | (x_?tmpvalQ)[___]) -> x, Infinity, 
     Heads -> True]]];
```

This helper function generates a set of replacements based on the `tmp$` variables found in the expression and a pure function defining what each of these variables should be replaced with. An example of such a function would be `{{# -> x}, {# -> y}}`, following the original question post.

```
replaceUnique[expr_, sym_, replf_] := 
 With[{e = expr /. {sym :> Unique[tmp]}}, 
  Fold[ReplaceAll, e, getreplacements[e, replf]]];
```

This is the core function of this solution. It performs the replacement of the chosen `sym` to a set of unique temporary symbols using `Unique[tmp]`, generates the list of replacements with `getreplacements`, and then uses `Fold` to perform each set of replacements in order for each unique variable generated. As an example:

```
replaceUnique[f[a, f[a, b]], a, {{# -> x}, {# -> y}} &]
```

> {{f[x, f[x, b]], f[y, f[x, b]]}, {f[x, f[y, b]], f[y, f[y, b]]}}

If you would like to precisely match the suggested output formatting, you may use `Flatten` as well.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation! Is it also possible to replace the head of expressions, such as `f`?

Comment: @ryuku That was more complicated than it should have been, but yes, it's possible. See the edited `getreplacements` for that functionality. The extended `Cases` is primarily to ensure that heads are treated as symbols rather than as expressions with arguments.

Comment: I just can't seem to make it work for me. Trying `replaceUnique[f[a, f[a, b]], f, {{# -> x}, {# -> y}} &]` leaves the `f`'s as `tmp$` variables.

Comment: Please try clearing `getreplacements` and using the newer edited version of it.

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for overlooking your edit.

Comment: Somehow I thought I could easily adapt `replaceUnique` to use `ReplaceList` instead of `Fold @* ReplaceAll`, but I must have gotten lost along the way: `replaceUnique[expr_, sym_, values_] := Module[{s, syms, rules},
  With[{expr2 = Module[{res},
      {res, syms} = Reap[
        expr /. {sym :> Sow[Unique[s]]}];
      res
      ]},
   syms = Flatten@syms;
   rules = Thread[syms -> #] & /@ Tuples[values, Length@syms];
   ReplaceList[expr2, e_ :> (e /. #) & /@ rules]
   ]]` (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Since the same pattern (`a`) is to be replaced in different ways in different positions, it seemed to me that the use of `Position` might be necessary:

```
replaceAllWays[expr_, rules : {(a_ -> _) ..}] :=
  With[{pos = Position[expr, a]},
   ReplacePart[expr, #] & /@ 
    Flatten[Outer[List, ##] & @@ Outer[Rule, pos, rules[[All, 2]], 1],
      Length[pos] - 1]
   ];

replaceAllWays[f[a, f[a, b]], {a -> x, a -> y}]
(*  {f[x, f[x, b]],
     f[x, f[y, b]],
     f[y, f[x, b]],
     f[y, f[y, b]]}  *)
```

Other examples (to replace `k` instances of `a` in `n` independent replacements can be done in `n^k` ways):

```
replaceAllWays[f[a, f[a, b]], {a -> x, a -> y, a -> z}] // Length
(*  9  *)

replaceAllWays[
  f[a, f[a, b] + f[a, a]], {a -> x, a -> y, a -> z}] // Length
(*  81  *)
```

Update: To work with other replacements, include `RuleDelayed`, as requested in a comment.  Update 2: I think this problem is perhaps not well define on arbitrary replacement rules.  When one rule might change the structure of an expression, it's hard to see how there will always be a consistent way to interpret a set of rules (the order that the rules are applied in the code matters in the second example below).

```
ClearAll[replaceAllWays];
replaceAllWays[expr_, rules : {(Rule | RuleDelayed)[a_, _] ..}] :=
  With[{pos = Position[{expr}, a]},
   First@Fold[ReplacePart, {expr}, Reverse@#] & /@ 
    Flatten[Outer[List, ##] & @@ 
      Outer[ReplacePart[
         Rule[##], {2} -> Replace[{expr}[[Sequence @@ #1]], #2]] &, 
       pos, rules, 1], Length[pos] - 1]
   ];

replaceAllWays[
 f[f[a, b], a], {head_[a, arg__] :> g[a, arg], 
  head_[a, arg__] :> h[a, arg]}]
(*  {f[g[a, b], a], f[h[a, b], a]}  *)

replaceAllWays[
 f[a, f[a, b]], {head_[a, arg__] :> g[a, arg], 
  head_[a, arg__] :> h[a, arg]}]
(*  {g[a, g[a, b]], h[a, g[a, b]], g[a, h[a, b]], h[a, h[a, b]]}  *)
```

Comment: Is it too much to ask that it can handle more complex rules, such as in `Replace[f[f[a, b], b], head_[a, arg__] :> g[a, arg], All]`? In this case, it only replaces the second `f` with `g`, because it is following by an `a`

Comment: @ryuku "In this case, it only replaces the second f with g"-- is what it does what you want? Or do you want something else?

Comment: It is what I want, I'm just unsure as to how one can extend `replaceAllWays` to include this functionality

Comment: @ryuku I see. It's the `RuleDelayed` instead of `Rule`. I extended the function definition to include both cases.  Please see the updated function.

Comment: Trying `replaceAllWays[f[f[a, b], b], {head_[a, arg__] :> g[a, arg]}]` does not give the intended result. Should I write the `RuleDelayed` differently?

Comment: @ryuku It's trickier than I thought at first. `ReplacePart` does not do pattern matching so it cannot do it by itself.  See if the update works as desired.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with `replaceAllWays[f[a, f[a, b]], {head_[a, arg__] :> g[a, arg], 
  head_[a, arg__] :> h[a, arg]}]`, which returns `{f[a, g[a, b]], f[a, g[a, b]], f[a, h[a, b]], f[a, h[a, b]]}`, but should return something like `{g[a, g[a, b]], g[a, h[a, b]], h[a, g[a, b]], h[a, h[a, b]]}`

Comment: I have specified my original question, which I hope is okay to do. Please see the edit on my post. Also, I will not be available for a couple of hours, as it is getting late where I'm at. All your help thus far has been greatly appreciated, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
f1 = Join @@ Outer[f[#, f[#2, b]] &, #, #] &
f1 @ {x, y}
```

> {f[x, f[x, b]],
>    f[x, f[y, b]],
>    f[y, f[x, b]],
>    f[y, f[y, b]]}

```
f2 = Join @@ Outer[# /. f[x, y_] :> #2[x, y] &, {#}, #2] &;
f2[f[f[x, x], x], {f, g, h}]
```

> {f[f[x, x], x], f[g[x, x], x], f[h[x, x], x]}